# How to add systemd.setenv in GRUB2

Tags: linux, centos, grub2

I  would like to add `systemd.setenv=NSS_HASH_ALG_SUPPORT=+MD5` parameter in grub2 for centos7?

I don't know which files I've to modify, and which lines I've to insert this parameter.

Thaks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grub configuration is found in `/etc/sysconfig/grub` on CentOS 7 systems.

Within you will find the default kernel command line parameters, which you can edit.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd.lvm.lv=centos/root crashkernel=auto  vconsole.keymap=us rhgb quiet"
```

After editing the file, run `grub2-mkconfig` to regenerate the grub configuration.

```
grub2-mkconfig > /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```